# How to time a key press relative to a frame refresh on the monitor in kivy (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, timing

I'm developing an application in kivy for psych research that needs to record the delay between something being presented on the screen and the user pressing a key on the keyboard.  Actually implementing the timing is easy but I'm left with some delay variance that is inherent to the system and I don't know how to eliminate it.

If it was a constant delay I could just subtract it from the data but if it varies that is a confounding variable.

I realize there will be some input lag from the keyboard (though I haven't been able to find a source that explains what this will be - I've seen everything from 8ms to 200ms my own testing suggests it's maximum 30ms). What I would like to do is start a timer when a frame is displayed on the monitor and stop the timer when a key is pressed.

The relevant parts of my code are the testing screen and the keyboard listener.

Currently I have:

```
class TestScreen(Screen):
    def test_update(self,dt)
        self.ids.left_number.fontval = 200
        self.ids.right_number.fontval = 100
        response_time_start = time.clock()
```

I have a keyboard widget implemented:

```
class KeyboardListener(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyKeyboardListener, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        response_time_end = time.clock()
        if accept_input == 1:
            if keycode[1] == 'escape':
                keyboard.release()
            if text == 'f':
                print 'Response time: ' + str((response_time_end-response_time_start)*1000) + 'ms'
                Clock.schedule_once(self.parent.parent.test_blank,-1)
                Clock.schedule_once(self.parent.parent.test_update,1)

            return True
```

The test-blank method accepts no input so I only get the response time for the test_update frames. Doing it this way, I'm trying to estimate the maximum delay by just holding down the 'f' key on the keyboard and looking at the distribution of response times that I get.

A typical set looks like this:

```
Response time: 1.64090357165ms
Response time: 5.11166324745ms
Response time: 13.2276396813ms
Response time: 1.88118446611ms
Response time: 25.9535446244ms
Response time: 22.024679318ms
Response time: 22.4933714233ms
Response time: 7.03038157825ms
Response time: 6.90109826654ms
Response time: 2.90326047379ms
Response time: 25.264461365ms
Response time: 24.6594282983ms
```

This seems like a large variance to me and I would love some advice on how to better measure this.  A response time of under 5ms is also surprising as this seems faster than the built-in keyboard debounce time that I would have expected.

In the .kv file:

```
<TestScreen>:
    id: test_screen
    RelativeLayout:
        id: test_layout
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.89,0.75,0.62,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        CountDownLabel:
            id: count_label
            text: str(self.val)
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: 200
            markup: True
        LeftNumber:
            id: left_number
            text: self.val
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .25, .25
            font_size: self.fontval
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.25,'center_y':0.5}
            markup: True
        RightNumber:
            id: right_number
            text: self.val
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .25, .25
            font_size: self.fontval
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.75, 'center_y':0.5}
            markup: True
        CrossLabel:
            id: cross_label
```

Example number class:

```
class LeftNumber(Label):
    val = StringProperty('')
    fontval = NumericProperty(100)
```